# Opening a password protected zip file in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, zip

My friend wants to send me an encrypted zip file that he created using

```
$ zip -e file.zip file2.zip
```

Will I be able to open that with the native Windows XP pk zip implementation?

Comment: Please complete your Question. With what exactly do you want to open it?

Answer (score 2):

### Linux/Mac OS X

At first, you need the password to open it.

Try

```
unzip file.zip
```

It'll prompt password from you. Of course, you have to install `unzip` first, if it doesn't exist, if you want to extract that file using command line tools.

### Windows

If Windows Explorer can't open your encrypted ZIP file, you can install for example [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Windows do have support, but not for all encryption variations commonly used for password protecting ZIP file. 7Zip includes support for many other formats too, and rather good command line tools, in addition to good Explorer integration. For executing from command line, use

```
7z.exe e file.zip
```

If you don't have your 7Zip installation on your path, use (for example)

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e file.zip
```

It'll prompt your password, and then extract files to your current folder. Run `7z.exe` without parameters to see all switches and commands.

Comment: actually, i meant on windows xp.  sorry for the confusion.  see edit above.

Comment: I updated my answer too.

Comment: @Jon: remember to accept helpful answers to your questions (this and another questions), see for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will be able to:

[image]

Comment: Beware that Windows Explorer only supports the ZIP 2.0 encryption algorithm, which is so weak that it's not worth using.

Comment: Glad you pointed that out @grawity